# Procedure or function Sp_Add_Moeny has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am passing the below parameters from c# form. But getting error. I can not find where the reason is. Please help me.

```
SqlParameter[] arrParam = new SqlParameter[3];
arrParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@mRegNo", SqlDbType.BigInt, 8);
arrParam[0].Value = Convert.ToInt64(m);

arrParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@amount", SqlDbType.Decimal);
arrParam[1].Value = money;

arrParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@intResult", SqlDbType.Int);
arrParam[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

int result = objDUT.ExecuteSqlSP(arrParam, "Sp_Add_Moeny");
```

Here is the function below:

```
public int ExecuteSqlSP(SqlParameter[] arrParam, string strSPName)
{
        OpenConnection();
        _mDataCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _mDataCom.CommandText = strSPName;
        _mDataCom.CommandTimeout = 30;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrParam.Length; i++)
        {
            _mDataCom.Parameters.Add(arrParam[i]);
        }

        _mDataCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int intResult = Int32.Parse(_mDataCom.Parameters["@intResult"].Value.ToString());

        CloseConnection();
        DisposeConnection();

        return intResult;
}
```

Please suggest a solution. Thanks

Comment: Where do you definte, Sp_Add_Moeny how many params does it expect?

Comment: What error? What does googling it find? Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying arguments that stored procedure isn't expecting. Make sure that your stored proc has three arguments corresponding to

> 1.mRegNo
>   2.amount
>   3.intResult (you haven't posted a snippet of your proc, which you should so that    we can  see how you've declared this in SQL)

if the number of parameters are same then check if parameter data types match with their counterparts in stored proc

Hope this helps !

Comment: I declared the parameters in the proc like this '@mRegNo as bigint',
 '@amount as decimal',
 '@intResult int output'   I still cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: here is the proc code, :   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Add_Moeny] 
 '@mRegNo' as bigint,
 '@amount' as decimal,
 '@intResult' as int output  
AS
BEGIN 
    declare '@maxPayId', '@bMessage', '@comment 
Execute [sp_IA] '@mRegNo','@amount','@maxPayid','@bMessage','@comment','@intResult output  

if (@@error<>0)                        
 begin                        
    set '@intResult'=1                        
    return '@intResult'                        
     end 
END